# NullPointerException while using loadUserByUsername

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

This is a spring security login example from [here](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-security-mysql-hibernate/). I changed annotations configuration to XML and made few changes to the url's it should point.I am able to login with credentials in db successfully. If i enter wrong password i get invalid message. But if i enter a username that is not in db or simply submit without values, i get nullpointerexception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.xxxx.service.CustomUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(CustomUserDetailsService.java:37)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

**CustomUserDetailsService.java**

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private LoginDAO loginDAO;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        com.xxxx.model.Login domainUser = loginDAO.getUser(userName);

        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        return new User(
                domainUser.getUserName(), // line 37
                domainUser.getPassword(),
                enabled,
                accountNonExpired,
                credentialsNonExpired,
                accountNonLocked,
                getAuthorities(domainUser.getRole().getId())
                ); 

            }

            public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer role) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(role));
            return authList;
            }

            public List<String> getRoles(Integer role) {

                List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

                if (role.intValue() == 1) {
                roles.add("ROLE_MODERATOR");
                roles.add("ROLE_ADMIN");
                } else if (role.intValue() == 2) {
                roles.add("ROLE_MODERATOR");
                }
                return roles;
                }
            public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

                for (String role : roles) {
                authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl (role));
                }
                return authorities;
                }
}
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<http auto-config="true">

<intercept-url pattern="/success" access="ROLE_MODERATOR" />
<intercept-url pattern="/success" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />

<form-login login-page="/login.html"
default-target-url="/success.html"
authentication-failure-url="/error.html" />
<logout logout-success-url="/login.html" />

</http>

<authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
<password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Please someone point me where i have done wrong.

**EDIT :
LoginDAOImpl.java**

```
@Repository
public class LoginDAOImpl implements LoginDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session openSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public Login getUser(String userName) {
        List<Login> loginList = new ArrayList<Login>();
        Query query = openSession().createQuery(
                "from Login l where l.userName = :userName");
        query.setParameter("userName", userName);
        loginList = query.list();
        if (loginList.size() > 0)
            return loginList.get(0);
        else
            return null;    
    }
}
```

Comment: The NPE is at line 37 of CustomUserDetailsService please mark this line.

Comment: What does `LoginDao` look like?

Comment: It makes sense that you got the NPE. The method specifically returns null when the username does not match.

Comment: You'll have to go through the rest of the code and see what fits. I might suggest that you check out another tutorial.

Comment: Okay i checked domainUser for null and handled the exception. Now it working. But my question is how come the original code works without this addition of code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to access `userName` field of a `null` `Login` object.

As I can see, if *username* is not in DB you are returning `null` from your DAO, but you are not checking return value in your Service.

So, before creating a new `User` instance check if returned `Login` **is not null**. If it's `null` you should throw a `UsernameNotFoundException`.

Comment: Got it sir. Nice explanation. I added this code if (domainUser == null){ throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found" + userName);} in my service and its working now. But this is not in the tutorial link i mentioned above and its still working. That is my question now sir.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your application context (app-context.xml file) or try other xml files.

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```